# spark.components.VideoDisplay and the DoubleClick-Event

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I stumbled upon and interesting problem concerning spark's VideoDisplay-Component.
It seems that it doesn't dispatch *DoubleClick*-Events.

For better understanding look at the following code:

```
<s:VideoDisplay [..] doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="{trace('VideoDisplay_DoubleClick')}" click="{trace('VideoDisplay_Click')}" />
<s:Panel [..] doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="{trace('Panel_DoubleClick')}" click="{trace('Panel_Click')}"  />
```

The *Click*-Event works for both components. But the *DoubleClick*-Event is only handled by the *Panel*-Component.

Do you guys have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/VideoDisplay.html#eventSummary
In the events section.

doubleClick
"Dispatched when a user presses and releases the main button of a pointing device twice in rapid succession over the same InteractiveObject when that object's doubleClickEnabled flag is set to true.
from InteractiveObject"

If it doesn't work, then it's a bug.

But, have you set your object's "doubleClickEnabled" flag to true?

Oz

4dtext - website enhancement tools

Comment: As you can see in my example above I set the doubleClickEnable-Property to true.

I think it's a bug. I just replaced my VideoDisplays from the spark-Namespace with the old VideoDisplay's in the mx-Namespace for a different reason and all of a sudden the component dispatches the DoubleClickEvent.

However, I'll report it to Adobe.